# Instagram API Privacy Policy

Tags: api, instagram, privacy-policy

I am trying to get access to Instagram's API, but I believe I would need to write a Privacy Policy for my application, but have no experience with that. 
Can anyone help please?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. We're not policy writers. Find an example somewhere and adapt it to your needs.

Comment: you dont really need, it just put my app homepage url for it and got approved

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about writing a privacy policy and not directly about programming or software coding.